# Water Damage to Droid 4 Non Removable Battery

Tags: motorola-droid-4, water-damage

I dropped my Droid 4 in a clean toilet.  The battery is not removable so I am concerned that waiting 2 or 3 days while it "drys out" in rice is a complete waste of time.  I am hoping someone can tell me if there is any hope that it may function normally again or should I buy a new one.

I'm not a patient person so waiting for it to dry out is sort of annoying.

Answer (score 1):

If you have warranty then give it to the service centre and tell them to clear the water logs, if you don't have then you can do it by yourself and there are lots of tutorials available for dismantling and assembling. Keeping the phone with battery and water could cause some short circuit and there are possibilties that you battery will be dead completely. So act fast